# Calculating delta values between two nested dictionaries (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, delta

I'm trying to find the delta between numeric values in two nested dictionaries that look something like this:

```
d1= {"device":"ABC","filteredData":{"device_id_1":{"deviceValueMap":{"ifInDiscards":{"i":"5"},"ifInErrors":{"i":"0"},"ifOperStatus":{"s":"up"},"ifOutDiscards":{"i":"0"},"ifOutErrors":{"i":"2"}}}}}

d2= {"device":"ABC","filteredData":{"device_id_1":{"deviceValueMap":{"ifInDiscards":{"i":"10"},"ifInErrors":{"i":"0"},"ifOperStatus":{"s":"up"},"ifOutDiscards":{"i":"5"},"ifOutErrors":{"i":"13"}}}}}
```

So, in this example I want the output to look like this:

```
{"ifInDiscards":5, "ifInErrors":0, "ifOutDiscards":5, "ifOutErrors": 11}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over both pairs at `deviceValueMap` level, then do the substraction

```
result = {}

for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(
        d1['filteredData']['device_id_1']['deviceValueMap'].items(),
        d2['filteredData']['device_id_1']['deviceValueMap'].items()):
    
    if "i" in v1 and "i" in v2:
        result[k1] = int(v2['i']) - int(v1['i'])

print(result)
# {'ifInDiscards': 5, 'ifInErrors': 0, 'ifOutDiscards': 5, 'ifOutErrors': 11}
```

That only works if both are ordered in same order and contains same keys (the `if*` ones)

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks! As far as I know, they should always be in the same order, but if no- can I use sort()?